# Anaconda took over my Python path

Tags: python, anaconda

I install Anaconda for jupyter notebooks and suddenly all my python environments are a mess. If I run `which python` I get a path to a python install within Anaconda. Does anyone know how to install Anaconda without it taking over Python?

There is a confusing section in the [conda wiki](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html#installing-conda-on-a-system-that-has-other-python-installations-or-packages) that says you can install Anaconda even if you have Python running, but it then explains that the Python path would be changed, which is I think what one would **not** want to happen.

In my case, I use `pyenv` and it's not clear how Anaconda would work with that kind of a setup.

Comment: You can just change your path variable back

Comment: @GrantWilliams it would be great if you could elaborate on how that could be done. I looked and didn't see where it had set my python path. Also, wouldn't that then prevent anacondas from function properly?

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming you are not using windows. If so the same concept applies but solution is more lengthy.

At the end of installation Anaconda asks if you want to add in entry in your `.bashrc` (or `.bash_profile`) file. This would make anaconda the "default" python in your system.

**quick fix** Just run this command then use python

`export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH`

**proper fix** look into the `.bashrc` file in your home directory for similar line which adds the anaconda path to `PATH` variable and remove it (or comment it out).

**Explanation** `PATH` is a special variable in bash which determines which directories to look for program binaries to execute. When you try to launch python shell searches for python executable in each of these directories and uses the first one found.

I suggest learning shell scripting basics and 
[More about `PATH`](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acar)

Comment: I am on a Mac. I unmarked this as the solution because it doesn't really solve the problem satisfactorily. Ideally, one could run condas without having to set the PATH each time. Another solution I've come across is to set the path differently: `export PATH=$Path:/path/to/conda`. This works somehow, leaving the main python directory unchanged, but it fails when you try to use condas environments. The `source activate <env name>` command fails to find the environment. So I'm still searching for a solution here.

Comment: Could you elaborate your question about in which cases you want to use system default python and where you want anaconda python? And why do you want to use both simultaneously

Comment: it is a matter of managing the different python environments that I use for different projects. The problem with Anaconda seems to be that the default installation sets the main python path to be be its Python, which is a problem if you use Python for development in other projects. I published a description of what I did here: http://humanscode.com/better-python-environment-management-for-anaconda

Comment: For this I would suggest using conda environments alone and leave out all others (virtualenv, system default). Create one conda env for each project and set this in you IDE as well. However you'll have to corresponding env every time you use shell to work with project. This practice is very common.

Comment: the trouble that I experienced, which led me to the alternate solution that I described [here](http://humanscode.com/better-python-environment-management-for-anaconda), was the problem described in my first comment above.